# What constrains do I have to add to make a button scale for iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, ios8

I am not a huge user of Interface Builder.

I am working with Size Classes of the kind Compact/Regular (for all iPhones portrait), right now.

I have added a button but this button is not scaling up for different sizes of iPhones.

What constraints I have to add to that button to make that button scale according to the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to get larger with screen size regardless or the aspect ratio of the button, add constraints for leading, trailing, top, and bottom from the button to the parent view.

If you want to maintain some aspect ratio, set constraints on leading, trailing, and top or bottom from the button to the parent view. Then set an aspect ratio constraint on the button itself.

In any case, be sure to set whatever numerical constant you want on the various constraints. Annoyingly, Xcode 6 does not seem to let you select constraints of different types and set them all at once like Xcode 5 used to. So it takes a few more clicks now.

Comment: Ah, I got it. You have to lock it to the border. Thanks!